# How does Google Analytics count conversion / goal completion (goalCompletionsAll) by various dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm pulling some Google Analytics data, and I'm interested in learning which page (page title) leads to more goal completion. Similarly with search keywords.

However, I'm not clear what constitutes as goal completion when given a page title. Unlike ga:goalPreviousStep3, which clearly tells me that it's the page url 3 steps prior to completing the goal, how do I know which page title or search keyword qualifies for goal completion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**chunsangh**, be aware that you are mixing various dimension/metric scopes:

- **Keyword** is of *session scope* (and same applies to conversion).
- **Page Title** is of *page scope*.

Building a custom report with Page Title as **Dimension** and Goal Completitions as **Metric** wouldn't make sense as there is no way how you can make a direct link between those two. Read this [brilliant article by Avinash](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/hits-sessions-metrics-dimensions-web-analytics/). Try using metric [**Page Value**](http://analytics.blogspot.cz/2012/07/understanding-and-using-page-value.html) metric instead.

To answer the other part of your quesion: **goal is accomplished when the [required conditions are met](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3046660?hl=en)**. You can review all the goals in *Admin* section.

Hope this helps!